# How to draw Message Sequence Charts?

Tags: delphi

Is there a component (preferably free) to help me draw [Message Sequence Charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Sequence_Chart)?

If not, how would you go about it?

[image: A Message Sequence Chart, yesterday]

---

Update: btw, I should have made it clear am not trying to create an app to allow users to manually draw MSCs, otherwise I would simply use TMS Diagram Studio (see my "answer" below).

What I want to do is to auto-generate MSCs from trace logs. So, I will write some code to parse the log file and then would like a components to allow me to define columns and then add arrows to show the message sequence of the trace log.

Comment: Eleven years later, I should add that I long ago chose [https://msc-generator.gitlab.io/msc-generator/](https://msc-generator.gitlab.io/msc-generator/) and have never regretted it. Great, free tool, with a great author who is very quick to respond to emails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is UML in some Delphi versions, see [Practical UML: A Hands-On Introduction for Developers](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31863).

A standalone tool like this may fit your needs : [EventStudio](http://www.eventhelix.com/EventStudio/features.htm). It let's you model complex interactions in a modeling language.

Anders Melanders [TStateMachine](http://melander.dk/delphi/statemachine) is a Delphi component which can be used to describe and simulate complex state changes.

Boian Mitov's [OpenWireEditor](http://www.mitov.com/products/OpenWireEditor) can be integrated into the Delphi IDE. Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but close.

Update :

JVCL (Project Jedi) has a component [TJvDiagramShape](http://help.delphi-jedi.org/unit.php?Id=2655), which has the primitives for drawing modeling diagrams.

[ModelMakerTools](http://www.modelmakertools.com/modelmaker/screenshots/sequence-diagram.html) has a Delphi interface, and is similar to TMS Diagram Studio.

Comment: +1 and I wish that I could make it more. If you know of any more components which would allow to develop tools for s/w developers, please pst. Thanks a 1,000,000

Answer (score 1):

I'm not attempting to answer my own question here, just posting to point out that the commercial component [TMS diagram Studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/diagram.asp) might be used, as this picture shows:

[image: A different Message Sequence Chart, yesterday]

However, it would still need some work for what I have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is also TeeTree from [Steema Software](http://www.steema.com/featurematrix/vcl) which is included in the VCL Pro version of TeeChart.

Comment: Doesn't that only draw charts?

Comment: No, They have a product called TeeTree which is an canvas upon which you can draw shapes and lines. For some reason they dont push it though.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link. A little too pricey for me, but still very nice.